# DateTime constraint on route with time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routevalues

How would a constraint for a route look like that needs to be in the format:`yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm`?

especially with the space there?

I got `@"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"` so far, but not sure about the rest

How's it done?

/M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way would be

```
@"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}"
```

But that wont guarantee that its indeed a Date Time Value, you will have to re-check post binding, maybe with Angelov answer.

The other thing to notice is that your URL will get an ugly `%20` for the space.

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure the format with the regex, but you probable want to ensure that the datetime is valid. You can try [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx)

Something like that:

```
public static bool IsDateValid(string s)
{
    DateTime d;
    return DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm",null,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,out d);
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the question

Comment: Using regex matching is the only way to create validation for your data? "How would a constraint for a route look like that needs to be in the format:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm?"

Comment: He wants to create an asp.net-mvc route, which is based on regex matching your url to redirect the request to a handler.